# HP-UX - custom rsync path

Tags: rsync, hp-ux

There are a range of HP-UX 11.11 hosts I'm unable to install rsync (I'm limited to a non-privileged user)

I've extracted both rsync binary and libpopt.sl, libiconv.sl, libintl.sl from the depots into one of that user's directories:
/home/zenith/rsync/

Problem is,
I can't get my RH Linux box communicating with it:

```
rsync -e --rsync-path=/home/zenith/rsync/rsync --compress=9 -pgtov --filter=+rs_/'*.log' --exclude='*' zenith@192.102.14.18:/home/zenith/service/logs/ /u01/rsync_depot/service/192.102.14.18/

/usr/lib/dld.sl: Can't find path for shared library: libintl.sl
/usr/lib/dld.sl: No such file or directory
sh: 1644 Abort(coredump)
```

I've added to the remote host .profile

```
export SHLIB_PATH=/usr/lib:/home/zenith/rsync
export PATH=$PATH:/home/zenith/rsync
```

but still, no libintl.sl is found.
How can I initialize the correct env variable/ get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

How about adding LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable and adding the directory where the shared library is?

Comment: mdpc, I've tried adding it but I still get a 
    /usr/lib/dld.sl: Can't find path for shared library: libintl.sl
    /usr/lib/dld.sl: No such file or directory
(that path contents are,
-r-xr-x---   1 zenith       users      1019904 Mar  7 18:34 libiconv.sl
-r-xr-x---   1 zenith       users        98304 Mar  7 18:31 libintl.sl
-r-xr-x---   1 zenith       users       139264 Mar  7 18:35 libpopt.sl)

Comment: The only ugly workaround I got so far was creating a BASH file named rsync (and renaming rsync bin to rsync.bin)
    export SHLIB_PATH=$SHLIB_PATH:/home/core/rsync
    /home/zenith/rsync/rsync.bin $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8

Any idea what's amiss?